# Should i use lookup-lists instead of a lot of multiplication?

Tags: c#, performance, comparison, multiplication, lookup-tables

in my application I have a very large array of bytes, its a flattened 3 dimensional array, we populate the array using 3 nested for loops (x, y, z) and then we get the values we want by using a little bit of math, most specifically:

To get an index in the array:

```
return x + z*SizeX + y*SizeX*SizeZ;
```

and to return the x/y/z coordinates, given an index:

```
int index = pos;
var y = (ushort) (pos/SizeX/SizeZ);
pos -= y*SizeX*SizeZ;
var z = (ushort) (pos/SizeX);
pos -= z*SizeX;
var x = (ushort) pos;

return new BlockPos(x, y, z, index, this);
```

First off, I would imagine the second one can be made more efficient, i just don't know how to do it, any help there would be appreciated :P

My main quesion is, would it be faster for me to make a lookup table for the y and x values (populating when the class is loaded) or is it faster to just leave the multiplication in there?

*edit*
This math is called a LOT in some cases, so if it would be faster, even for a longer startup it would make a differance better.

Comment: This is c#, edited main post to show that.

Comment: I've taken it out as a sentence and added it as a tag. This has the advantage that the code is now nicely formatted as c#.

Comment: Thank you, i didnt realize that it reformatted the code into the language specs! Also, multi dimensional arrays are generally perceived as bad, and these array can have millions of bytes in them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *most* languages and architectures, multiplication will become one (or a few) machine instructions. Whilst those instructions may be relatively expensive, they should still be cheaper that performing a lookup operation - and a lookup operation may very well require a multiplication anyway.

E.g. "locate the 4th element of the array" will be

```
<array base address> + (3 * <array element size>)
```

The only optimization I'd recommend given your pseudo code is to perform the "constant" operations (e.g. `SizeX*SizeZ`) once, and store those results.

Comment: Any tips for improving the second one, or is that all the better im going to get it? :)

Comment: @Merlin33069 - If you can force all of the sizes involved to be powers of 2, then you can avoid multiplication and use bit-shifting instead.

Comment: Thank you, I looked that up and its LOADS faster most of the time, *sometimes* it is the same speed, but the old way is never faster. <3 https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9690967/speedy.png

Answer (score 0):

These might speed you up;

- Make SizeX, SizeY, SizeZ constants
- Precompute SizeXZ = SizeX * SizeZ and the others (also as constants);

pre-computing array indices will not gain you much as the precomputed list will be pretty large and looking into it will probably not be faster as doing very little easy math.

Array operations in C# are relatively slow (compared to some other languages) because most access is bounds checked. There are some ways to get around that;

- put a tight arrayloop in an unsafe section and use pointers
  see [Large array arithmetics in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111026/large-array-arithmetics-in-c-sharp)
  or google for 'matrix multiplication unsafe c#'
- Mono has a parameter to skip bounds checking. It *might* be faster in your case

Another speedup can be had to arrange your math loops in such a way that your math processing accesses the large array sequentially. In that way each access benefits from the fact that the data is usually already fetched into the cpu-cache by the previous computation. So structure the x,y,z loops in such a way that you get index=1, index=2, index=3 etc. And NOT index = 0, index= 256, index = 512 etc..

Comment: Unfortunately, the sizes are dynamic, I did precompute the SizeX*SizeZ, that helped a little, I wasnt going to precompute the entire list, just the results for the x/z multiplications (it would be an array of no more than 2056 integer results). Thank you for your time.